# UI Distortion when I set my targetVersion to 4.0

Tags: android

I have implemented application using 10 as minSdkVersion so according to the link :  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target. So 2.3.3 will become targetSdkVersion by default.

This application was working fine on the devices having build 10 and 4.0 version. Now when I have changed minSdkVersion to 14 my UI was distorted. At this stage my minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion will be 14.

Now when I change targetVersion to 10 which was my previous one and minSdkVersion to 14 it's working.

Expected result : It should work as it is if I am upgrading my target and minimum sdk version to 14 from 10. Also please specify any additional steps required to migrate between this 2 versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting your `targetSdkVersion` to 10 if your `minSdkVersion` is 14. **`targetSdkVersion >= minSdkVersion` always**.

`minSdkVersion` is the **minimum version** that you support. If your application works on all devices from 2.3.3 and up, set your `minSdkVersion` to 10 and leave it there.

`targetSdkVersion` is the **tested version** that you support. If you use features from 4.1.2, but that aren't required in your application, `targetSdkVersion` should be 16.

Realistically, this is how it should go:

1. Find the API that supports the minimum amount of features to run your app. This is the minimum version. (I find this is usually between 4 and 8.)
2. Then, find the highest API you can test on and use features from. This is your target version. (This is almost always the latest version which, at the moment, is 16.)

These are explained very clearly in [the documentation you linked](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: What should I do to get spinner's look of 2.3.3 and not allowing my users to have lower version the 16?

Comment: You'd have to get the spinner image yourself. But this seems silly to me. 2.3.3, 3.x, and 4.x all have radically different aesthetics. You should conform to the new system styles to give your users the best app experience.

Comment: Eric this is not silly or wrong requirement , I want to have common behavior or look and feel for all the versions. Even you can achieve this by providing no theme at application level without doing anything or applying and image to spinner.